# use an static function from a protocol in a function, objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, function, inheritance, protocols

I want to use an static function from a protocol in a function:

```
    @implementation IPadPanoramaViewController
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
     [self.view addSubview:[PanoramaContent getPanoramaContentByPanoramaItem:[[PanoramaListItem alloc] init]]; 
     [super viewDidLoad];
}
@end

        @protocol PanoramaItemProtocol

        + (UIView *) getPanoramaItemBySection;

        @end


        @implementation PanoramaContent
    + (UIView *) getPanoramaContentByPanoramaItem:(id<PanoramaItemProtocol>) itemKind {

                return [itemKind getPanoramaItemBySection]; //here is the problem "unrecognized selector sent to instance"
        }
    @end
```

I wish "PanoramaListItem" don't be a NSObject

Comment: What's "PanoramaListItem"?  You don't use it in your example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've defined `getPanoramaBySection` to be a class method, when you're calling it on an instance. In the protocol declaration, replace the `+` with a `-`.

Answer (score 0):

First, static methods can only be sent to a class. If you don't want to create an object, the parameter of getPanoramaContentByPanoramaItem: should be of type Class. You can use something like the following:

```
 + (UIView *) getPanoramaContentByPanoramaItem:(Class)itemKind {
     UIView *v = nil;
     if( [itemKind respondsToSelector:@selector(getPanoramaItemBySection)] ) {
         v = [itemKind getPanoramaItemBySection];
     }
     return v;
 }
```

and to send the message:

```
[self.view addSubview:[PanoramaContent getPanoramaContentByPanoramaItem:[PanoramaListItem class]]];
```